# Getting black screen animation when root controller change in iOS 13 and Xcode 11

Tags: viewcontroller, ios13, xcode11, swift4.2, uiwindow

I am changing rootviewcontroller of my uiwindow using below code.

```
let tabbarVc: EPTabbarViewControllers = storyBoardIdentifiers.main.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EPTabbarViewControllers") as! EPTabbarViewControllers
let navControl = UINavigationController(rootViewController: tabbarVc)
navControl.navigationBar.isHidden = false
window?.rootViewController = navControl
```

This works fine on xcode 10 and iOS13 but getting issue in xCode 11 and iOS13. I am getting black screen. How can I stop this animation? Please see the video below for the reference.

[image]

Comment: Try to add this line at the end of your code: `self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()`

Comment: I have already tried but not working. Thank for suggestion.